# Real Analysis, Folland Proposition 2.30 Modes of Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Proposition 2.30 - Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in measure. Then there is a measurable function $f$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure, and there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\}$ that converges to $f$ a.e. Moreover, if also $f_n\rightarrow g$ in measure, then $g = f$ a.e.

Attempted proof - Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in measure. This means for every $\epsilon > 0$, $$\mu\left(\{x:|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|\geq \epsilon\}\right)\rightarrow 0 \ \ \text{as} \ \ m,n\rightarrow \infty$$ Thus we can choose a subsequence $\{g_j\} = \{f_{n_j}\}$ from $\{f_n\}$ such that if $E_j = \{x:|g_j(x) - g_{j+1}(x)| \geq 2^{-j}\}$, then $\mu(E_j)\leq 2^{-j}$. Let $F_k = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_k$, then $\mu(F_k)\leq \sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\mu(E_j) \leq \sum_{j=k}^{\infty}2^{-j} = 2^{1-k}$, so we have $\mu(F_k)\leq 2^{1-k}$ by subadditivity of $\mu$.

I am trying to take Folland's approach and expand upon it a bit to include more detail but after this part I am lost on where and why he goes where he goes. Any suggestions or alternative ways of proving this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Folland's book is very tersed, and this Theorem 2.30 is a good exemple of such tersed style.

> Theorem 2.30 - Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in measure. Then there is a measurable function $f$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure, and there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\}$ that converges to $f$ a.e. Moreover, if also $f_n\rightarrow g$ in measure, then $g = f$ a.e.

This theorem actually contains FIVE (relevant) "propositions":

> P1. Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in measure. Then there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\}$ which is Cauchy a.e.
>
> P2. Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy a.e.. Then there is a measurable function $f$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e.
>
> P3. Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in measure and converges to $f$ a.e.. Then $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ measure.
>
> P4. Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in measure and there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\}$ which converges to $f$ in measure. Then $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ measure.
>
> P5. Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ converges in measure to $f$ and $g$. Then $g=f$ a.e.

Folland's proof is actually a concatenation of tersed proofs of those five propositions.

Let us prove each of those propositions individually and then, let us see how they combine to prove Theorem 2.30.

**Proof of P1**:

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in measure. This means for every $\epsilon > 0$, $$\mu\left(\{x:|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|\geq \epsilon\}\right)\rightarrow 0 \ \ \text{as} \ \ m,n\rightarrow \infty$$

Thus we can choose a subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\}$ from $\{f_n\}$ such that
$$\mu\left ( \left \{x:|f_{n_j}(x) - f_{n_{j+1}}(x)| \geq \frac{1}{2^{j}}\right \} \right ) \leq  \frac{1}{2^{j}}$$
Let, for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\geq 1$,
$$F_k = \bigcup_{j=k}^{\infty}\left \{x:|f_{n_j}(x) - f_{n_{j+1}}(x)| \geq  \frac{1}{2^{j}}\right \}$$
then
$$\mu(F_k)\leq \sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\mu\left (\left \{x:|f_{n_j}(x) - f_{n_{j+1}}(x)| \geq  \frac{1}{2^{j}}\right \}\right) \leq \sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{j}} = \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$ so we have $\mu(F_k)\leq \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$.

Let
$$ F=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_k $$
Since, for all $k\geq 1 $, $F \subset F_k$, we have that, for all $k\geq 1 $, $\mu(F) \leq \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$. So we have that $ \mu(F) =0$.

Now if $x \notin F $, then there is $k$ such that $x \notin F_k$. Given $\epsilon>0$, let $M\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $M\geq k$ and $\frac{1}{2^{M-1}} <\epsilon$. For all $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$, if $i\geq j \geq M$, then
$$|f_{n_j} -f_{n_i}| \leq \sum_{l=j}^{i-1} |f_{n_l} -f_{n_{l+1}}|\leq  \sum_{l=j}^{i-1}\frac{1}{2^l}\leq \frac{1}{2^{j-1}}\leq \frac{1}{2^{M-1}} \leq \epsilon$$

So the subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\}$ is Cauchy a.e.

**Proof of P2**:

Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy a.e.. The there is a measurable set $F$, such that $\mu(F)=0$ and $\{f_n\}$ is pointwise Cauchy on $F^c$. That means for every $x \notin F$, $f_n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$, and so is convergent.

For every $x \notin F$, let us define $f(x)$ to be $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)$. If $x \in F$, let us define $f(x)=0$.

Then we have that $f_n \to f$ a.e  and  $f$ is measurable.

(**Remark**: Note that $F$ is a measurable set, so $F^c$ is a measurable set as well. We have that $f|_{F^c}$ is the pointwise limit of measurable functions $f_n|_{F^c}$, so $f|_{F^c}$ is a measurable function. Also, it is easy to see that $f|_{F}$ (which is identically zero) is a measurable function. So $f$ is measurable.)

**Proof of P3**:

Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in measure and converges to $f$ a.e.. Since  $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in measure, we have that, for every $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta>0$, there is $N\in \mathbb{N}$, such that, for all $n,m \geq N$ $$\mu\left(\{x:|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\}\right)<\delta$$

Note that, given any $n\geq N$, if $|f_n(y) - f(y)|\geq \epsilon$, then there is $M\geq N$ such that for all $m\geq M$, $|f_n(y) - f_m(y)|\geq \epsilon/2$.
In other words: given any $n\geq N$, if $y\in\{x: |f_n(x) - f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$, then $y\in \bigcup_{M=N}^\infty\bigcap_{m=M}^\infty \{x:|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\}$.

Yet in other words: given any $n\geq N$,
$$ \{x: |f_n(x) - f(x)|\geq \epsilon\} \subset \bigcup_{M=N}^\infty\bigcap_{m=M}^\infty \{x:|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\}$$

Note that $\{\bigcap_{m=M}^\infty \{x:|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\}\}_M$ is a monotone non-decreasing sequence of measurable sets and for any any $M\geq N$
$$\mu \left (\bigcap_{m=M}^\infty \{x:|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\} \right)\leq \mu(\{x:|f_n(x) - f_M(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\})\leq \delta$$
So using the continuity of the measure from below, we have

$$ \mu(\{x: |f_n(x) - f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}) \leq \mu\left( \bigcup_{M=N}^\infty\bigcap_{m=M}^\infty \{x:|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\} \right) =\\=\lim_{M \to \infty} \mu\left(\bigcap_{m=M}^\infty \{x:|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\} \right)\leq \delta$$

So, we proved that,
for every $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta>0$, there is $N\in \mathbb{N}$, such that, for all $n \geq N$ $$\mu\left(\{x:|f_n(x) - f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}\right)<\delta$$

So, $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ measure.

**Proof of P4**:

It is an imediate consequence of
$$\{x:|f_n(x) - f(x)|\geq \epsilon\} \subset \{x:|f_n(x) - f_{n_j}(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\} \cup  \{x:|f_{n_j}(x) - f(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\}$$

The set $\{x:|f_n(x) - f_{n_j}(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\}$ can have arbitraly small measure, because $\{f_n\}_n$ is Cauchy in measure.

The set $ \{x:|f_{n_j}(x) - f(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\}$ can have arbitraly small measure, because the subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\}$ converges to $f$ in measure.

**Proof of P5**:

Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ converges in measure to $f$ and $g$. Then, for any $\epsilon>0$,

$$ \{x : |f(x)-g(x)|\geq \epsilon \} \subset \{x:|f(x) - f_n(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\} \cup  \{x:|f_n(x) - g(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\}$$

Given any $\delta >0$ for $n$ sufuciently large we have

$$\mu(\{x:|f(x) - f_n(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\})\leq \delta/2 $$
and
$$\mu(\{x:|f_n(x) - g(x)|\geq \epsilon/2\})\leq \delta/2 $$

So, for any $\epsilon>0$, for all $\delta>0$
$$\mu( \{x : |f(x)-g(x)|\geq \epsilon \} )\leq \delta$$

So, for any $\epsilon>0$, $$\mu( \{x : |f(x)-g(x)|\geq \epsilon \} )= 0$$
But $$ \{x : |f(x)-g(x)|\geq 0 \}= \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \{x : |f(x)-g(x)|\geq 1/k\}$$
So, $\mu(\{x : |f(x)-g(x)|\geq 0 \})=0$. So $f=g$ a.e.

**Proof of Theorem 2.30**: (following the logic in proof presented Folland's book)

By P1, there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\}$ which is Cauchy a.e.

By P2, since $\{f_{n_j}\}$ which is Cauchy a.e., there is a measurable function $f$ such that $f_{n_j}\rightarrow f$ a.e.

Since  $\{f_{n_j}\}$  is a subsequence of  $\{f_n\}$, we have that  $\{f_{n_j}\}$  is Cauchy in measure and since  $f_{n_j}\rightarrow f$ a.e., by P3, we have that  $\{f_{n_j}\}$ converges to $f$ measure.

By P4, since $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in measure and the subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\}$
converges to $f$ in measure, we have that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ measure.

By P5, we have that the limit for the convergence in measure is unique a.e.

**Remark**: In thersed proof, Follands concatenate the proofs of those five points. In particular, to prove P3, he uses estimates made for P1, which helps to make the proof shorter.

Comment: I think this may be a trivial question, but how exactly do we conclude that $f$ is measurable in P.2?

Comment: The result you mentioned holds for any measure when the limit exists everywhere. It also holds when it exists almost everywhere only when we are working with a complete measure, which may not be the case here.

Comment: In the book, he reminds the reader that the set of points $x$ such that the limit of a sequence of measurable functions {$f_n$} exists is a measurable set, and that if $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets, a function $f$ is measurable on $X$ iff it is measurable on $A$ and $B$. I tried to apply this with the sets $F$ and $F^{c}$ and prove that the function $f$ you defined is measurable on each of them separately, but haven't been able to do it.

Comment: @Km356 , Ok. Let me explain in all details. Note that $F$ is a **measurable set** and we have that $f|_{F^c}$ is the pointwise limit of measurable functions $f_n|_{F^c}$, so $f|_{F^c}$ is a measurable function. It is easy to see also that $f|_{F}$ (which is identically zero) is a measurable function. So $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Km356 You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The interest of having the $2^{-k}$ upper bound is that you can sum it, and then use Borel-Cantelli...

Comment: I see but Borel-Cantelli is not introduced until later.